# HTACCESS Redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, collision

In my htaccess file, I have the following two rules. I would like to make the second one occur on the condition that the first one doesn't match. Currently, they both get run. Is there any way around the collision?

```
redirect 301 /lorem/ipsum-keyword.html /lorem/dolorem-keyword.html
RewriteRule (.*)-keyword.html$  /dir/file.php?param=$1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite for both and use the L option to ensure that no further rewriting occurs. Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^lorem/ipsum-keyword.html$ http://yourdomain.com/lorem/dolorem-keyword.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*)-keyword.html$  /dir/file.php?param=$1
```

Comment: You need to adjust the first rule to match your exact document. I'll update.

Comment: That ^ was critical too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might use a rewrite rule for the 301 and add the L flag, so it will ignore the following rules.

I can't test it, but this should work:

```
RewriteRule /lorem/ipsum-keyword.html$  /lorem/dolorem-keyword.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*)-keyword.html$  /dir/file.php?param=$1
```

Comment: The first rule isn't catching at all... even when i remove the second

Comment: Then your "Redirect 301" wouldn't work either. You might have to make the rule relative and not absolute. AS I don"t know your file system strucutre I can't tell you what is wrong. The sytax of the rule should be OK.